# Why don't my numbers add correctly

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I'm running

```
function howOldAreYou(day,month,year) {
var age;
age = (day) + (2015-year) + (month*12);
return age
};


document.write(howOldAreYou(parseFloat(prompt("yo day"))),(parseFloat(prompt("yo month"))),(parseFloat(prompt("yo year"))));
```

I know I got the age formula wrong, but I should get some added number back, and instead I'll get this: If I put it "1" in the first prompt, "2" in the second, and "3" in the third, I'll get this on the document "NaN23". I feel like it's a small parenthesis problem, but I can't figure it out, and help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the formula is wrong, but I can't duplicate your output. It looks like you are entering an invalid number as the "day"

Comment: Yes, it is a parenthesis problem. You can solve it yourself by counting them carefully and working out which opening parenthesis matches with which closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `howOldAreYou` function is being called after the first prompt, so you're passing, for example: `howOldAreYou(1, undefined, undefined)`

Design choices aside, you can make what you're doing work like this:

```
function howOldAreYou(day,month,year) {
    var age;
    age = (day) + (2015-year) + (month*12);
    return age
};

var day = parseFloat(prompt("yo day"));
var month = parseFloat(prompt("yo month"));
var year = parseFloat(prompt("yo year"));

document.write(howOldAreYou(day, month, year));
```

Or, to keep it how you originally had it, the correct format would be:

```
document.write(
    howOldAreYou(parseFloat(prompt("yo day")), 
                 parseFloat(prompt("yo month")), 
                 parseFloat(prompt("yo year"))));
```